# Django print sqlite db data in template

Tags: python, django, sqlite, templates, view

I'm new to django and I'm having a little difficulty getting my database data to print onto my page. I'd appreciate help - and I know I'm doing something silly but I've kinda hit the wall.

I have the DB set up and I can access the data in it without any issues:

python manage.py shell

```
>>> from homepage.models import User, Oncall
>>> user_data = User.objects.all()
>>> names = []
>>> for x in user_data:
...  names.append(x.first_name + ' ' + x.last_name)
>>> names
[u'Arthur Mencke', u'John Doe']
```

So then in my views.py I have:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
from homepage.models import User, Oncall
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.template.defaulttags import register

def index(request):
        now = timezone.now()
        users = User.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'homepage/index.html')

def getUsers(request):
        users = User.objects.all()
        name_list = []
        for x in users:
                name_list.append(x.first_name + ' ' + x.last_name)
        return name_list
```

And in my index.html file:

```
{% if name_list %}
        {% for x in name_list %}
                {{ name_list.x }}
        {% endfor %}
{% else %}
        <b>no users</b>
{% endif %}

{{name_list|length}}
```

This will always show up in the browser with:

```
no users 0
```

I've also tried name_list[x] and mucked around with it quite a bit with no luck

Any ideas?

Cheers, Arthur

Comment: You need to pass the context of `users` or `name_list` to the template

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, you are not passing the context in `index` view, take this example:

```
def index(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'homepage/index.html', {'users': users}) # notice here we are adding our context to be used in template, you need pass it explicitly
```

Then in `index.html`:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <span>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Aamir! That did the trick. It seems quite simple in hindsight but the django template language and relationships between files takes a little getting used to.